# Want Open a link in internal and if it contains a link,then clicking it should open in external browser in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I have a browser which on Wireless connectivity opens a Uri otherwise opens a html page.
In both cases the Uri or html page opens in internal browser. Both these pages contains links.I want to open the links in external browser if user clicks them. But  they always open in internal browser.

Following is my code:

```
private void Information_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool hasNetworkConnection =
         NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211;
    if (!hasNetworkConnection)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("index_en.html"))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

                browser.NavigateToString(html);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        browser.Navigate(Uri);         
    }
}
```

And xaml is :

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="browser" Margin="0,78,0,0" Navigating="on_browser_navigation" />
```

How do I handle the click of link in the Html page or the Uri?

EDIT: I handled the Navigation event

```
 private void on_browser_navigation(Object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
      {

              e.Cancel = true;
              WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
              wbt.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
              wbt.Show();

      }
```

But this  does not show the required behavior in case of Uri.It directly opens the Uri in external browser.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself in your question: "I want to open the links in external browser if user clicks the. But always they open in internal browser". Do you mean that you want the links from the internal browser to open in the external browser?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.But all i want to do is first open a uri or html page in internal browser.The content of  html page or uri  further contains links which when clicked should open in external browser.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event in the WebBrowser control.

In there check the `e.Uri` to see if it is an external link. If so, set `e.Cancel
 = true;` and then use the `WebBrowserTask` to lauch the external link in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.but how to check whether e.Uri is external link or internal

Comment: @IndianBird You could parse e.Uri as a string and see if it starts with "http://" and then you'll definitely know it's external to the app. Depending on the links in the content you're using you should be able to determine if this is external or not.

Comment: @IndianBird, @Matt Lacey is right, also you can check domain name, not just http://, because internal pages still can be the ones with http:// in their links. For example if opened page contains test.com, than any link from that page, containing test.com probably will be internal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check to see if the URI is external or external by looking at the URI.Host:

```
if (!e.Uri.Host.Contains("www.mysite.com"))
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
else 
{
   'do something
}
```